# How to visualize an image array with 2 color channels using openCV?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, imshow

I have some image arrays with a shape of (128,256,2) which have two color channels. I am trying to open the image array using the openCV's imshow but I am continuously getting the following error: >

```
Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 2
```

I understand openCV can't open image array with two color space. Is there any way to open the image with the two color channels or to compute element-wise average and convert it an array with one color channel? Kindly help please!

```
> cv2.imshow("Window", img)
```

Comment: Add a third black channel. Then you should be able to view it. OpenCV  does not recognize an image with only 2 channels.

Comment: @fmw42, can you help me write the code for adding an additional third black channel please?

Comment: This is just a slightly rephrased clone of [question you posted 14 hours prior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75125990/3962537). Same error, same lack of detail. Not really sure what it got an upvote for....

Comment: Solution is the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open an numpy array image with two color channels using openCV's imshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125990/how-to-open-an-numpy-array-image-with-two-color-channels-using-opencvs-imshow)

Comment: @fmw42 [No. it's not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125990/how-to-open-an-numpy-array-image-with-two-color-channels-using-opencvs-imshow#comment132574040_75125990)

Comment: @beaker My comment was in reference to the answer below by Ci Long.  That is one way to convert 2 channels to 3 channels by adding a black image as the third channel. The link above and which you reference is not my answer.

Comment: @fmw42 In the comment I linked, the OP states that adding a third all-black channel does not work for them.

Comment: Then there was something wrong with how he did it. It should work just fine if done correctly, if all you want is to view the image. One can also just duplicated one of the channels and add that as a 3rd channel

Comment: @fmw42 Of course adding a 3rd channel is a (the typical?) way to do it, but the OP has stated that it doesn't work for them, twice. There's either something wrong with the way they're doing it, or there's something different about their data, or maybe the data that they're trying to visualize isn't a simple BGR image channel. For example, why is the first value in the OP's float32 array `1.1458042`? Looks odd, right?  So we can either keep making guesses as to what the OP is trying to do, or we can convince them to clarify exactly what they need and how they're trying to achieve it.

Comment: @beaker. Where do you see that the data is float and has that value for the first element?  I do not see that in OP question. And yes, the OP has not give enough reproducible code

Comment: @fmw42 It's in the comments on Ci Leong's answer.

Comment: If he saved a float image to disk, then it would appear black. If he viewed it, it would appear black if no scaling was done, since the values are all very low compared to the range 0 to 255.

Comment: @fmw42 Bingo...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that demonstrates adding a black channel to two channels of an image in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read a 3 channel image
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# separate channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

# create black image the same size as image
black = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)

# replace the red channel with black
result = cv2.merge([b,g,black])

# save results
cv2.imwrite('lena_black.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

If you already have a 2 channel image, then simply create the black image and use `np.dstack([2-channel-image, black])` to make a 3 channel image.

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV does not recognise images with only 2 channels, the solution is to add a black channel.

OpenCV images are represented as `numpy` arrays:

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMG)

# This returns <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.
type(img)
```

Now we can use `numpy` functions to add the 3rd channel (black):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

H, W, _ = img.shape
img = np.append(img, np.zeros((H, W, 1)), axis=-1)

cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Credits to @fmw42.

---

Or, you could take the element-wise average across channels, and display it as a grayscale image:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.average(img, axis=-1)

cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: @JacobIssac Could you let me know what is your image format? Can the 2-channel image be read by `cv2`? If so, how?

Comment: @JacobIssac I have added an element-wise average approach, could you check if it solves your display problem?